# Legal impossible dungeon?

Tags: ios, king-of-thieves

In the iOS game king of thieves, can you create a dungeon that is possible to complete for the editor, but impossible for another player during normal gameplay?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The editor requiring you to clear your own dungeon twice ensures that this doesn't happen.